# Which definition for 'agency' in 'moral agency'?

Tags: meaning

> 2. [agency](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/agency) =  [mass noun] Action or intervention producing a particular effect
>
> 2.1 = [count noun] A thing or person that acts to produce a particular result:

How do you determine/deduce which definition applies to [moral agency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_agency)?? Please explain the steps or thought processes; I’d like to try to resolve this myself in the future?

Comment: It might be the possibility of moral action, or the fact or an instance of moral, or the entity performing a moral act, depending on the context. Nothing means anything outside a context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these definitions is a good fit in the phrase *moral agency*.

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agency) gives as definition 2 of *agency*:

> the capacity, condition, or state of acting or of exerting power

This is a much better fit.  Someone who has *moral agency* has the capacity to make moral decisions and act on them.

Answer (score 1):

Moral agency in the link you cite refers to judgments about the rightness or wrongness of a particular action.

Although judgments exist only insofar as there  are persons doing the judging, we can speak of the process of making such judgments in the abstract, leaving out the individual flesh-and-blood judge, and placing our focus on the idea of right or wrong that is the impetus or motive for the judgment.  Thus, we speak of "moral agency", that is, the power of the idea of right and wrong to produce an effect.

Of course there is no such entity as an idea that is separate from the people who can have the idea. But we can still speak of ideas as if they have agency. In actuality the concept is more complex: "people-having-ideas".  But it gets to be very clumsy when we start hyphenating our words like that, and pretty soon, we're creating neologisms and trailing off into arcane jargon.